# fwrite(): send of 249 bytes failed with errno=10053 An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: laravel, mailgun

I am using mailgun with laravel to send emails to gmail account for testing purpose but got issue

> fwrite(): send of 249 bytes failed with errno=10053 An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine..

Answer (score 0):

As response clearly shows that some local machine software causing the issue. Try to uninstall the protocol using softwares like Skype.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your SMTP is correct.
In my case it was wrong smtp host server. I was first using the sandbox domain, provided by Mailgun, which had US based smtp server.
Once I switched to my domain which was EU based with different smtp, I had the same issue.